# Cmake is failing to call a custom command

Tags: cmake

I have gone through everything I could find in the past hour and nothing has worked, what am I missing. I am trying to run a `.sh` file through CMake using `add_custom_command` and it is not working.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)
project(learnvulkan)

set(OUT out)

set(VULKANSDK_VERSION 1.2.182.0)

set(GLFW_DIR /mnt/Projects/GLFW)
set(VULKANSDK_DIR /mnt/Projects/vulkan/${VULKANSDK_VERSION}/x86_64)

set(VULKANSDK_LIB ${VULKANSDK_DIR}/lib/libvulkan.so)
set(GLFW_LIB ${GLFW_DIR}/libglfw3.a)

include_directories(
    ${VULKANSDK_DIR}/include
    ${GLFW_DIR}/include
)

file(GLOB src_list
    src/*.cpp
    src/*.hpp
    src/**/*.cpp
    src/**/*.hpp
    src/**/**/*.cpp
    src/**/**/*.hpp
)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(${OUT} ${src_list})

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT no_output
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compileShaders.sh
    COMMENT "Compiling shaders"
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${OUT}
    ${GLFW_LIB}
    ${VULKANSDK_LIB}
    dl
    pthread
    X11
    Xrandr 
    Xi
)
```

Comment: Nothing depends on `no_output`, so the command to create it will not run

Comment: How would I make something depend on no_output

Comment: If you want some actions to be performed **every build**, then use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).